# How to bind a memberfunction to a library callback?

Tags: c++, callback, bind, member-functions

I am searching for a solutiuon to assign a memberfuction `Callback` to the `extLibrary->OnNewFrame` where `OnNewFrame` is  a pointer-to-function type.

```
class Test
{
    public:
        void init();
        void Callback(ImageDataType, int);
    private:
};
    
void Test::init(){
    extLibrary=new CameraLib;
    extLibrary->OnNewFrame = Test::Callback; 
    //OnNewFrame is  a pointer-to-function type
}
    
void Test::Callback(ImageDataType data, int n){
    doImageProc();
}
```

If I change the Code above to `static void Callback(ImageDataType, int)`, the code runs fine, but of course I can not access the variables of the Test Class in `Callback` .

I think I have to init the Class and pass the memberfunction to the lib's pointer-to-function type after, but I don't know how to do that properly.

**EDIT**
Sorry, this is my first post and I provided wrong and incomplete information. I will try to improve this post as far as I am able to.

To clarify what the library actually needs:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *GrabNewFrame) (HANDLE h, int i);
//this is the pointer to function definition
...
//after that in the lib-class:
class CameraLib
{
...
public:
    GrabNewFrame  OnNewFrame;
...
}
```

`OnNewFrame` gets called by the lib every time a frame arrives from the camera.
So as far as I know, I have to assign my own void function to `OnNewFrame` . Without OOP this works like a charm. But with classes I do not get a memberfunction assigned to `OnNewFrame` ...

Comment: Not easy to answer without knowing the type of `CallbackFunc` (or equivalently, the typedef behind `stdcall_FuncPointer`) Some libraries support passing a "user data pointer" which can be used to smuggle a pointer to the object. Does yours?

Comment: Unfortunately C++ does not work this way. If the library doesn't offer the means to associate an opaque pointer, with the callback, it is not compatible with C++, in that respect.

Comment: Have a look into std::bind

Comment: @Botje
The typedef `behind stdcall_FuncPointer` is `typedef void (__stdcall *CamLib::newFrame)(HANDLE aHandle, int aStreamIndex)` .

Im not sure about your second point. The lib callback gives me the raw camera image with a index.

Comment: @glades Doesn't help; you can't convert that to a function pointer.

Comment: @N.K. Then the callback must be a non-static member function of `CamLib`. Casting a function pointer pretty much makes sure that the behaviour is undefined. (I'm fairly sure that you have missed or misunderstood something about this library.)

Comment: `stdcall_FuncPointer` is what you use for the cast, but maybe thats the wrong type to begin with. What is the type of `extLibrary->CallbackFunc` ? If thats the same then, what moldnilo said

Comment: `__stdcall` and member function pointer? As far as I'm aware these are incompatible as calling convention for the latter normally is `__thiscall`, though I might err ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes it is the same as `extLibrary->CallbackFunc` .

Comment: Where would the library get the object from on which to call the member function pointer on??? Is there another setter for?

Comment: btw there is something fishy about your comment. This typedef declaration `typedef void (__stdcall *CamLib::newFrame)(HANDLE aHandle, int aStreamIndex)` declares an alias named `newFrame` (and I am not sure if its right syntax). The declaration for the alias `stdcall_FuncPointer` must be elsewhere, its not this one

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number 
sorry I changed it to the correct code. I had to modify the actual func names of the lib, because its sensitive data... 
`extLibrary->onNewFrame = static_cast<newFrame>(Test::Callback);`

Comment: @Aconcagua I am used to `typedef void (Foo::*bar)()` but maybe I remember wrong, or maybe it doesnt matter

Comment: ok, you should include information also in the qeustion, not only in comments. Though, for now, there is not much solution we can offer. It rather looks like you misunderstand how it is supposed to be used. If the type of the callback is pointer to member of some class then it must be member of that class not something else.

Comment: btw if you cannot disclose parts of the code you can still provide a [mcve] by writing a non confidential small example code, unless of course the techniques applied are essential and confidential, but then we cannot help anyhow

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh, totally overlooked before – adding the calling convention is fine, but the asterisk indeed is at the wrong place...

Comment: @OP prefer `using newFrame = void (CamLib::*)(HANDLE,int);` it does not require a twisted mind to read :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number

you were absolutly right. I did not provide the important information. Hopefully my new version of the post is better now. Thanks to all for the kind answers.